replace last line on sd card text (gpx) file on esp32
i am trying to write a gpx track from gps to an sd Card on an ESP32. Since i am not really familiar with c, i struggle with this task:
every time i write a new track segment to the file i want to first remove the closing lines like so:
  if (gpsFixExists && dateIsValid && timeIsValid)
  {
    if (state.currentGPXFile == "")
    {
      String filename = "/" + String(state.dateYear) + String(state.dateMonth) + String(state.dateDay) + "_" + String(state.timeHours) + String(state.timeMinutes) + String(state.timeSeconds) + ".gpx";
      state.currentGPXFile = filename.c_str();
      File gpxFile = SD.open(state.currentGPXFile.c_str(), FILE_WRITE);
      // Write GPX header and metadata
      gpxFile.println("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\" ?>");
      gpxFile.println("<gpx version=\"1.1\" creator=\"Open Rally Computer - https://github.com/pcace/open-rally-computer\">");
      gpxFile.println("<metadata>");
      gpxFile.println("<name>" + filename + "</name>");
      gpxFile.println("<desc>Track log generated by Open Rally Computer</desc>");
      gpxFile.println("</metadata>");
      gpxFile.println("<trk><name>Track Log</name><trkseg>");
      gpxFile.close();
    }

    // Open the file to append data
    File gpxFile = SD.open(state.currentGPXFile.c_str(), FILE_WRITE);
    if (gpxFile)
    {
      // Move to the end of the file, then seek back to overwrite the closing tags
      long position = gpxFile.size() - strlen("</trkseg></trk></gpx>") - 1; // Adjusted to account for newline characters
      gpxFile.seek(position);
      // Write the new track point
      gpxFile.println("<trkpt lat=\"" + String(state.currentLatitude, 6) + "\" lon=\"" + String(state.currentLongitude, 6) + "\">");
      gpxFile.println("<ele>" + String(state.currentAltitude, 2) + "</ele>");
      gpxFile.println("<time>" + String(state.dateYear) + "-" + String(state.dateMonth) + "-" + String(state.dateDay) + "T" + String(state.timeHours) + ":" + String(state.timeMinutes) + ":" + String(state.timeSeconds) + "Z</time>");
      gpxFile.println("</trkpt>");
      // Re-append the closing tags
      gpxFile.println("</trkseg></trk></gpx>");
      gpxFile.close();
    }
  }


these two lines are not correct:
      long position = gpxFile.size() - strlen("</trkseg></trk></gpx>") - 1; // Adjusted to account for newline characters
      gpxFile.seek(position);

how do i correcly replace the closing line with the new track segment?
Thanks a lot!

you could use File.find. https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/stream/streamfind/

You could do this by picking up the position in the file before you write the closing (ephemeral) part of the file. Then when you do the next write, use seek() to set it to the position that you saved.
I have tested this out on an ESP32, with the code below, and it works fine.
String filename = "/text.txt";
File f = SD.open(filename, FILE_WRITE);
if (f) {
    f.println("Data to keep");                       
    int intPosition = f.position();
    f.println("ephemeral_1");

    delay(2000);
    
    f.seek(intPosition);
    f.println("More data to keep");                       
    intPosition = f.position();
    f.println("ephemeral_2");
    f.close();                                             
}  

When you read back the code at the end, it gives this:
Data to keep
More data to keep
ephemeral_2

with ephemeral_1 missing.

like so: https://github.com/pcace/open-rally-computer/commit/5880423b7b4bcec075465e80dee5dba328e52c57?diff=unified&w=1
?
